# What would cause PhantomJS to hang on startup?

Tags: phantomjs

I'm running PhantomJS 1.9.1 from Terminal on Mac OS 10.8.4, like so:

$ phantomjs

I get the PhantomJS prompt:

phantomjs>

But no matter what I type (including console.log('hello world'), etc.), nothing is printed to the terminal in response.

Am I launching it with incorrect parameters, or not setting it up properly after startup, or is there some other problem anyone can guess?

If I execute $ phantomjs test.js, the code in test.js does execute and get printed to the terminal.

Comment: what if you type in phantomjs prompt: console.log('hello world!'); and press enter?

Comment: I tried that.  It doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently installing PhantomJS through Node Package Manager may have something to do with this issue.  If I download and install PhantomJS for Mac directly, then the REPL works as expected.